Create a logit GAM species prediction raster using Terra
I am trying to predict the occurrence of a species (presence/absence) using a GAM in R. I have fit the GAM, but I get an error when I try to  make the prediction to spatial data with terra::predict(). I get this error:
# Error invalid name(s)

I also do not understand why my predictions aren't binary (ie 1/0 for presence/absence)?
library(terra)
library(mgcv)
library(sf)

#polygons to generate random points within
v <- vect(system.file("ex/lux.shp", package="terra")) |> st_as_sf()

#get a raster from terra 
r <- rast(system.file("ex/elev.tif", package="terra"))

# Create 50 random points
set.seed(50)
pnts <- st_sample(v, size = 50, type = "random") |> st_as_sf()

# Return the exact raster value the point lies on
pnts_r <-  terra::extract(r, pnts, method = "simple") 

# Add occurrence column
pnts_r$occ <- as.factor(sample(0:1, 50, replace = TRUE))

# Fit the GAM
mod_gam <- mgcv::gam(formula = occ ~ elevation, 
                     data = pnts_r,
                     family = binomial(link = "logit"),
                     method = "REML")

# Predict using our training data
predict(mod_gam) # Why aren't the responses 1s and 0s?

# Predict using the entire raster
terra::predict(mod_gam, r, fun = "predict", na.rm=TRUE) 
# Error invalid name(s)

I understand the variable names in the model need to be identical to those in the raster, but in this case there is only 1 ("elevation") and its identical in both.

Your q is not reproducible, and rather theoretical.

@Friede Sorry I don't quite understand how this isn't reproducible. Are you unable to run the code?

Haven't checked completely, stopped reading in line 3 as st_as_sf() is used, while library(sf)is missing.

ok @Friede I edited the post to include sf

You have the order of arguments wrong in predict.
To use terra::predict the first argument should be a SpatRaster but you use the gam model. Since "predict" is a generic function, the implementation of predict is based on the class of the first argument, and this will take you to mgcv::predict.gam instead).
Example data
library(terra)
library(mgcv)
v <- vect(system.file("ex/lux.shp", package="terra"))
r <- rast(system.file("ex/elev.tif", package="terra"))
set.seed(50)
pnts <- spatSample(v, size = 50)
pnts_r <- terra::extract(r, pnts, method = "simple") 
pnts_r$occ <- sample(0:1, 50, replace = TRUE)
mod_gam <- mgcv::gam(occ ~ elevation, data = pnts_r, 
      family = binomial(link = "logit"), method = "REML")

Test the model, use argument type="response" if you want probabilities
p <- predict(mod_gam, type="response")
head(p)
#0.3965005 0.6287751 0.5908377 0.4722339 0.4477870 0.3605875 

And now with the raster data; again with type="response".
x <- terra::predict(r, mod_gam, type="response")

x
#class       : SpatRaster 
#dimensions  : 90, 95, 1  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
#resolution  : 0.008333333, 0.008333333  (x, y)
#extent      : 5.741667, 6.533333, 49.44167, 50.19167  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#coord. ref. : lon/lat WGS 84 (EPSG:4326) 
#source(s)   : memory
#varname     : elev 
#name        : elevation 
#min value   : 0.3231922 
#max value   : 0.6545229 

Inspect
plot(x)
# plot(x > .5)
points(pnts, col="red")


Alternatively, you can keep the order you have, by naming the arguments:
terra::predict(model=mod_gam, object=r, type="response")


What would we do without you? Thanks!

After a lot of fiddling I think I've answered my two questions. Maybe this will be helpful for someone later on.

The response isn't binary, but rather the probability of occurrence. This can be further manipulated into a presence/absence raster by setting a threshold (typically 0.5).

terra::predict() will work given a new raster (or stack) if you first convert them to a dataframe with terra::as.data.frame(r, xy = TRUE) for example.



if you use a data.frame as first argument to predict, you are not using terra::predict, as that method is only called when the first argument is a SpatRaster. Therefore, the output is not a SpatRaster either. With generic functions, prepending the package:: does not work as you expect.

You really shouldn't threshold your estimated response, just plot the estimate probability of occurrence for all your data points.
